# Is it possible to install SQL instances with different Collations in a SQL Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cluster, sql

We have a two node active-active SQL Server 2008 Cluster. Running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

The three excisting instances have Latin1_General_CI_AS as the Server Collation. I need to add an instance with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as the Server Collation.

Is this a supported configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every MSSQL Server instance is a complete, stand-alone database server system.

The Server collation is, therefore, unique to each instance.

This is obvious when you install an instance - you can specify the server collation at that moment.